# Form action not refreshing properly

Tags: php, html

I have a problem whit form submission. I have a html form and the action simpli doesnt want to work. maybe i am doing something wrong, but here take a look at it:

```
<form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
    <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" style="width:300px;">
    <select id="type" name="type">
        <option value="0">Matrix</option>
            <option value="1">LoL</option>
            <option value="2">Dota 2</option>
    </select><br />
    <textarea rows="30" cols="90" placeholder="Content here" name="content"></textarea><br />
    <input type="submit" value="DODAJ">

</form>
```

so when i click on the button i does refresh the page but nothing is displayed. I't worked in local but when i upload it online nothnig, just a blank page. And the stuff that has to go to the database doesnt go. no errors, no nothing.

help?

Here's the complete code for that add.php page:

```
<?php

include '../php/db/init.php';
include '../php/db/connection.php';
protect_page();
admin_protect();


if(isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])){

    if(isset($_POST['title'], $_POST['content'], $_POST['type'])){
        $title = $_POST['title'];
        $content = nl2br($_POST['content']);
        $content_short = substr($content,0, 150);
        $type = $_POST['type'];

        echo $type;
        die();

        if(empty($title) or empty($content) or empty($type)){
            $error = 'Potrebno je popuniti sva polja!';
        } else {

            $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO articles (article_title, article_content, article_content_short, article_timestamp, article_type) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)');

            $query->bindValue(1,$title);
            $query->bindValue(2,$content);
            $query->bindValue(3,$content_short);
            $query->bindValue(4,time());
            $query->bindValue(5,$type);

            $query->execute();

            redirect('http://www.matrixgamingns.com/admin/index.php');

        }
    }
?>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>Matrix Gaming Admin Panel</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/admin.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/reset.css">
    </head>

    <body>

        <div id="home">
            <div id="wrapper">

                <?php include 'adminmenusidebar.php'; ?>

                <div id="field">
                    <h3 style="font-size:22px;">Dodaj vest</h3>

                    <?php if(isset($error)){ ?>
                        <small style="color:#aa0000"> <?php echo $error?> </small>
                    <br/>
                    <?php }?>
                    <br />

                    <form action="add.php" method="post" autocomplete="off">
                        <input type="text" name="title" placeholder="Title" style="width:300px;">
                        <select id="type" name="type">
                            <option value="0">Matrix</option>
                            <option value="1">LoL</option>
                            <option value="2">Dota 2</option>
                        </select><br />
                        <textarea rows="30" cols="90" placeholder="Content here" name="content"></textarea><br />
                        <input type="submit" value="DODAJ">
                        <?php 

ini_set('display_errors','On');?>

                    </form>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>

</html>

<?php
} else {
            redirect('http://www.matrixgamingns.com/admin/index.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: Your `logged_in` session name is not defined anywhere in your posted code/question, so if it doesn't exist, it won't be set because there is nothing to check if it is `set`.

Comment: if you are getting a completely blank page it usually means a fatal error has happened and you do not have display_errors on, either look in your server error logs, or turn on display_errors in your php.ini file to on while debugging.

Comment: The `looged_in` variable is defined i know that for a fact because i am accessing the `add.php` page from my `index.php` page where `logged_id` is also check.

Comment: try doing print_r($_POST) and print_r($_SESSION) in add.php

Comment: Check the server error log with tail -t <filename> and submit the form again.It will tell you right away what is wrong

Comment: I am doing this:
`error_reporting(E_ALL);` in the `init.php` which i am including at the start of a page, should i do something else ?

Comment: @Vladimir I think you mean `header('Location: http://www.matrixgamingns.com/admin/index.php');` and not `redirect('http://www.matrixgamingns.com/admin/index.php');` probably the problem. Unless you have a function called `redirect`?

Comment: turn on display_errors, `ini_set('display_errors',1)` or just simply go onto your server and look in the error log.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i have afunction in javascript called redirect and it looks like this:

`function redirect($url){

    if (headers_sent()){
      die('<script type="text/javascript">window.location.href="' . $url . '";</script>');
    }else{
      header('Location: ' . $url);
      die();
    }    
}`

Comment: you cant call javascript functions from within php, this is probably the fatal error that is causing your page to not render. Its trying to execute a function that doesnt exist.

Comment: @Vladimir Have you tried it without the JS function? Mixing JS and PHP can be lethal at times.

Comment: @PatrickEvans As I just said to the OP. Lethal. And I can't see where the function is being called.

Comment: tried to remove my redirect function and insted put: header('Location: add.php'); and still nothing.

Comment: @Vladimir I suggest you use `header('Location: http://www.matrixgamingns.com/admin/index.php');` instead of using the JS function. JS and PHP mixed together can often be a pain in the neck, and I know what a "pain in the neck" feels like ;-)

Comment: @Vladimir The only thing that I can find besides that is `if(empty($title) or empty($content) or empty($type)){` try using `||` operators instead of `or`

Comment: ok ok just wait a sec to try everything out. i'v commented the lines where my redirect function is and put classical php header. Let me try

Comment: @Vladimir Or try `if($title === '' || $content === '' || $type === ''){` or `if($title === 'NULL' || $content === 'NULL' || $type === 'NULL'){`

Comment: OMG... i am so tired that i haven't saw the `die();`
OMG OMG OMG OMG.... seriously it's time for some sleep 48 hours of no sleep does this to a person...

Btw `or` is working correctly and it's working whit `header`...

Comment: @Vladimir Strangely enough, I was going to mention the `die` earlier actually.

Comment: Someone post the correct answer so i can check it as solved... Thnak you people a bunch!

Comment: @Vladimir Posted as answer. And you're welcome, glad it was solved. Now get some sleep ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `die()` after `echo $type;`

By including a `die()` function, it stops all in its tracks, just like `return` does and nothing gets executed afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the login form example posted here: [HTML Dynamic Forms Generator](http://phptoolcase.com/guides/ptc-forms-guide.html)

I downloaded the source code for the login form and it saved me lots of time.